# C# Datatable to Array of Array

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable, format, dataset

I am working on an Angular application. I want the data returned from datatable or dataset as array of array as shown in second ex of image. 
 this format:

```
0: {eid: "e101", ename: "ravi", esal: 1000}
1: {eid: "e102", ename: "ram", esal: 2000}
2: {eid: "e103", ename: "rajesh", esal: 3000}
```

I tried using NewtonSoft Json but still not getting desired result. Please guide how to achieve desired result

```
 string jsonString = string.Empty;
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.ItemArray));
            return jsonString;
```

or

```
string jsonString = string.Empty;
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
```

[image: image formats]

Comment: can you list out the difference between your desired results and your screenshots? it's becoming a real "spot the differences" contest here.

Comment: corrected post. Please advise

Comment: so how your current output look and why you showed a first screenshot?